# Hover Property not working on full Div but rather on children divs

Tags: html, css, transition

I have created a box like this:

[image]

Now i wanted to have a `hover` property to show a transition for this whole `div` like this:

```
.plan-box {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out !important;
  }

.plan-box :hover{
    transform: scale(1.03) !important;
}
```

but the issue is that rather than hover applying on while `div` it is applied on children divs, so for example if i hover over the `4.90` only that part is animated, but i want to animate whole box.

Full code snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/jzktwm7g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove space on hover `.plan-box :hover` to `.plan-box:hover`

```
.plan-box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03) !important;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/81cs7tpu/1/

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked. but can you please explain why space was causing issue?

Comment: css selector space means child element not target element

Comment: thankyou, i will accept the answer after time limit

Comment: `.test :hover` means you are targeting a `:hover` element (which can't exist) that is a descendant of an element with the class `test`, so something like `<div class="test"> <:hover> ` If you remove the space it means you want to apply the styles when hovering on the class.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply a negative scale on hover on children elements.

Here is a link that may help you: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-prevent-child-element-affected-by-parents-hover-state

Example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/zictzyap